# How to efficiently edit Markdown in the github issue tracker?

Tags: github

I like the fact that the github issue tracker supports Markdown. However, I find it relatively unpleasant to actually write Markdown in the github editor. It lacks many of the features of the Markdown editor on StackOverflow.

E.g., it lacks:

- a button to indent multiple lines of code by four spaces
- a button to add quote to the start of each line
- real time markdown preview
- fixed width font
- ability to insert image using imgur
- a confirmation dialog box when you close a browser window when you might otherwise lose your work

In particular, the inability to insert code blocks is probably the feature I miss the most.

Sure, I could write my markdown in a separate editor and then paste it into the github issue tracker, but this is not especially appealing. I could even use the StackOverflow editor if I was careful not to click "Ask Question", but that seems a bit silly.

#### Question

- Is there anyway of altering the text box in github to incorporate the editing features in StackOverflow?
- Or if it is better to type in another text editor, what's a particularly elegant way of doing that? (e.g., minimum steps, simple to move back and forward, good editor) Perhaps theres a way of clicking a text box and bringing up a Rich Markdown editor which when closed returns the contents to the original text box?

Answer (score 2):

You should appeal to GitHub to add one. Your argument is sound. Stack Overflow demonstrates editors can be functional, non-intrusive and tasteful.

Meanwhile, there might be a browser extension that does some of this. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpojebknccclkjabfngjlcknonpmhhol

Comment: +1 Thanks. I agree it would be a great feature to have. Also while the plugin looked promising, it didn't work for me, and it appears that it is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you might want to check MarkPad: http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/

Disclaimer: I have never used it myself (being on Ubuntu), only read about it watching the code52 project. I know it can edit posts of several blog systems, but I'm not sure if Github is in the list of supported web sources. Its syntax however is supported, for sure.